# Appropriate schema to design a notification system in django?

Tags: python, django, database-design, architecture

I am trying to create a notification system in Django. Is it better to have a notification_type field, user_id and a foreign key to different tables (like, comment, relationship tables)?

Or should they all have a separate table for each type of notification like "LikeNotification", "CommentNotification", etc in addition to all of them having a user_id field?

Design 1:

```py
class LikeNotification(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class CommentNotification(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PostNotification(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class BondNotification(models.Model):
    bond = models.ForeignKey(Bond, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Design 2:

```py
class Notification(models.Model):
    notification_type = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like = models.ForeignKey(Like, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bond = models.ForeignKey(Bond, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: You can use a `GenericForeignKey`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey although usually that is not a good idea, here it might make sense to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ContentType`:

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

This way you can have a `Foreignkey` to any model